# How to display youtube video on HTML page?

Tags: html, youtube, embed

First embeded src youtube video link  is

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
 <body>
<div>
    <object width="218" height="137"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/jpiU5Y8luOQ&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/jpiU5Y8luOQ&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="218" height="137">
    </embed>
    </object>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Second embeded src Video link is

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <object width="218" height="137"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwkeMx_OJxg&feature=related">
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwkeMx_OJxg&feature=related" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="218" height="137">
        </embed>
    </object>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The first html cod display video file on browser but the second didn't display. Can't the second one dispaly due to different video file type? Please
 guide me how to do.

```
                                            Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the second embed, you're linking the object directly to the watch page, which is not a valid video. You're providing it with a text/html page, not a video.

You can use this IFrame for the second one, and adjust the height/width as needed:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LwkeMx_OJxg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Youtube provides you with a sample code itself. You can't `embed` the videos, you'll need to use an iframe.

[Read this](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171780)

Answer (score 0):

When you right-click on the video page in Youtube, it gives you this code:

```
<object style="height: 137px; width: 218px">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/LwkeMx_OJxg?version=3&feature=player_detailpage">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/LwkeMx_OJxg?version=3&feature=player_detailpage" 
     type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
     allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="218" height="137">
</object>
```

Which works (I changed the width/height as per your example to check it works, and it does

Comment: The object method doesn't work always.

Comment: try this way. it is very simple http://www.developing4life.blogspot.com/2014/11/show-youtube-video-on-your-webpage-with.html