# HTML4:Why is this link of a video from Youtube not working in my website?

Tags: html, object, youtube, embed

So my website can't use HTML5, so I must use the good old HTML4 code, so I tried to go to youtube and get the code from there :

```
<object width="420" height="315">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZuNNhOEzJGA?hl=pt_PT&amp;version=3"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZuNNhOEzJGA?hl=pt_PT&amp;version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
```

It doesn't work. I've been checking online and found out some other people had the same problem, and by typing http: on embed it would work, but it doesn't, instead I get a flash player warning saying I have a object null trying to connect to youtube.

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: check here, may be you get any help
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344387/how-to-display-youtube-video-on-html-page

Comment: No, I didn't found my solution there, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one, its working or not

```
    <iframe title="YouTube video player" 

    class="youtube-player" type="text/html" 

    width="560" height="315" 

    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ny-M9KA5AhU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

here it is working fine

Comment: It works in all browsers, except for IE. Any ideas why?

EDIT: I got it working with the other code you gave me in IE, thanks a lot for the help :D

Comment: In my system its working fine in IE also. May be you are using older version.
your Welcome dude :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this one also:
[HTML - YouTube Videos](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp)

```
    <embed
    width="420" height="345"
   src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"
   type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
   </embed>
```

Comment: I tried that video, and it worked, but when I try with my video it doesn't. Am I copying it wrong?: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ny-M9KA5AhU

Comment: No, i tried you code its working fine here. it is working in full screen mode also.

Comment: Can you post the full code with my video please? So I can see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I just copied your code, nothing else. like
<html><body>your code</body></html> it worked.

Comment: Do you mean the video link I posted? That was just the link to the video I actually want to put in my website, the actual code I am trying to put on my website doesn't work when I put my video link there. So if I write my code like this:

<embed
width="300" height="210"
src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ny-M9KA5AhU"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</embed>

It doesn't work for me. All I get is a white screen.

Comment: I copied this code

       <object width="420" height="315">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZuNNhOEzJGA?hl=pt_PT&amp;version=3"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZuNNhOEzJGA?hl=pt_PT&amp;version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>

Comment: So weird, still doens't work... Would you mind have a look at my page and see what's wrong with it?